# SSAS/Power BI Row Level Security

Tags: powerbi, ssas, row-level-security

I have been using some very useful articles created by radacad (e.g. https://radacad.com/dynamic-row-level-security-with-manager-level-access-in-power-bi) to enable me to add some row level security to my SSAS data model that is the data source for a Power BI dashboard.

In essence, this is how I want my row level security to work.

1. If the logged in user is a manager and their department is LOD1, they can see the data for the whole organisation.
2. If the logged in user is a manager, they see their own data and the data of those in the same department as them.
3. If the logged in user is not a manager, they only see their own data.

The above represents each If statement in the below.

The following DAX near enough works perfect for this:

```
=
If(
MaxX(
Filter(
'Employee',
'Employee'[Email]=USERPRINCIPALNAME() )
,'Employee'[IsManager])="Yes" 
&&
MaxX(
Filter(
'Employee',
'Employee'[Email]=USERPRINCIPALNAME() )
,'Employee'[Department])="LOD1" 
,1=1
,
If(
MaxX(
Filter(
Employee,
[Email]=USERPRINCIPALNAME())
, Employee[IsManager])="Yes" 
&& 
MaxX(
Filter(
Employee,
[Email]=USERPRINCIPALNAME())
, Employee[Department]) <> "LOD1",
PATHCONTAINS(Employee[Department],
MaxX(
Filter(
Employee,
[Email]=USERPRINCIPALNAME())
, Employee[Department]
)),
[Email]=USERPRINCIPALNAME()))
```

However, the issue I have comes with using the MaxX expression. This is because within the Employee table, an employee can have more than one row, because an employee can have more than one department. Therefore, for those employees with more than one department, the Power BI dashboard is only showing them the data for the max dept selected.

If anyone could help me tweak my query to accommodate this obstacle and allow staff with more than one dept to see all their depts, not just the max, this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What's the reason for `PATHCONTAINS` ?

Comment: @SamNseir , it is so the logged in user can see the people who are in the same department as them  - if they're manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` or `VALUES` to get the list of departments for the user, then do a `IN` in the filter conditional.

Try:

```
var isManagerLOD1 = 
  COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(Employee,
      'Employee'[Email] = USERPRINCIPALNAME() &&
      'Employee'[IsManager] = "Yes" &&
      'Employee'[Department] = "LOD1" 
    )
  ) > 0

var managerDepartments =
  CALCULATETABLE(
    DISTINCT('Employee'[Department]),
    FILTER(Employee,
      'Employee'[Email] = USERPRINCIPALNAME() &&
      'Employee'[IsManager] = "Yes"
    )
  )

var isManagerDepartment = [Department] IN managerDepartments

var isUser = [Email] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()

return isManagerLOD1 || isManagerDepartment  || isUser
```

Comment: Hi Sam, many thanks for your response and work on this. I have tried using your DAX and unfortunately I get the following error:
"the expression contains multiple columns, but only a single column can be used in a true/false expression that is used as a table filter expression.

The only way the error would go is if I took out the conditions after the &&'s.

Any ideas?

Comment: I tested the above in Power BI Desktop and it worked. I guess SSAS is a little different. Did the error mention which part it didn't like? Can you share a screen shot?

Comment: Just had another dig and it is just this line in the 2nd var causing the issue  &&
  'Employee'[IsManager] = "Yes"

Comment: Where did `[Is Manager as Text]` come from? I tweaked it above to use `FILTER`, does that help?

Comment: Thanks Sam, adding the filter has removed the error. Ignore the renamed IsManager that I'd copied over. I'll get the team to test this out and hopefully it works as intended, I'll let you know! Quick question, there are 4 variables, why are only 3 in the return? Thank you

Comment: `managerDepartments` is a single table column containing all unique departments of the user. This is then used in `isManagerDepartment`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256529/discussion-between-lloyd-thomas-and-sam-nseir).

Comment: Updated answer above to resolve the `isManagerDepartment` not calculating correctly.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks Sam.